# How can I take a screenshot on an iPhone while Guided Access is on?

Tags: ios, screen-capture, accessibility, guided-access

**I’m trying to take a screenshot of a problem that’s occurring with Guided Access on my iPhone. Is this possible?**

I’ve had no luck with the usual method of simultaneously pressing the Home and Power buttons. This limitation exists even before I tap the Start button within Guided Access. Just being within the initial screen keeps the screenshot function from working.

I tried to find an answer to this question via standard web search, but found nothing.

Note: I’m using a beta version of iOS 13, but I assume that this same problem exists in iOS 12 and earlier.

Comment: Did you try using Assistive Touch from Settings app → General → Accessibility?

Comment: I haven’t, but I can. Not very familiar with it. Does it have a screenshot function?

Comment: Yes. I'll describe it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the AssistiveTouch feature built into iOS. AssistiveTouch gives you a software equivalent of Home button which can be used to perform a variety of device operations.

To enable AssistiveTouch go to Settings app → General → Accessibility → AssistiveTouch.

[image]

Once enabled, you'll notice a gray colored translucent overlay button on your device screen. Tap on the AssistiveTouch button → Device → More → Screenshot to capture a screenshot without touching any physical button on your device.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The captured screenshot can be viewed in the Photos app normally.

Comment: By “normally,” do you mean that the resulting screenshot will show the entire screen, but without the AssistiveTouch overlay?

Comment: @EJMak I actually meant that the screenshot taken this way will be saved in a similar manner as to one taken using physical buttons. Also, yes, the screenshot taken via AssistiveTouch will "not" include the overlay.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. Although I don’t rely heavily on the accessibility features in iOS. I’m impressed by their thoroughness and depth. Bravo, Apple!